# Counting number of characters and blank spaces in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

So I'm on the basics on MIPS programming and I have string as input. I need to count the average number of characters in every word. So I would need to count the number of blank spaces and number of other characters. Any idea how can I do that?

My code :

```
.data 

userInput: .space 40

.text
main:

li $v0, 8
la $a0, userInput
li $a1, 40
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example code that count the character string length.
Consider the string `Hello` the program return `5` since it's length is `5`.

```
.data
    message: .asciiz "Hello"
.text

main:
    li $t1,0
    la $t0,message

loop:
    lb   $a0,0($t0)
    beqz $a0,done
    addi $t0,$t0,1
    addi $t1,$t1,1
    j     loop
done:

    li   $v0,1
    add  $a0, $0,$t1
    syscall

    li   $v0,10
    syscall
```